# How to view the controller's resulting html in debug with ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is there a way that I can see, while debugging, the result (html, xml, json) of a Controller's action.

For instance, I have this in my controller:

```
    public PartialViewResult Reload()
    {
        return PartialView("Index");
    }
```

While debugging, I'd like to see what HTML will be sent back to the client.
Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to be able to see it? There may be an alternative to your end goal.

Comment: I know I can see the result on the client side. I use firebug to do that. I just want to know if it's possible to do it on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not easy, because partial view result is sent directly to httpcontext.current.response.output, it doesn't return string. You can use this extension method to catch it as string by filtering httpcontext output:

```
    /// <summary>Renders a view to string.</summary>
    public static string RenderViewToString(this Controller controller,
                                            string viewName, object viewData)
    {
        //Getting current response
        var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
        //Flushing
        response.Flush();

        //Finding rendered view
        var view = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controller.ControllerContext, viewName).View;
        //Creating view context
        var viewContext = new ViewContext(controller.ControllerContext, view,
                                          controller.ViewData, controller.TempData);

        //Since RenderView goes straight to HttpContext.Current, we have to filter and cut out our view
        var oldFilter = response.Filter;
        Stream filter = new MemoryStream(); ;
        try
        {
            response.Filter = filter;
            viewContext.View.Render(viewContext, null);
            response.Flush();
            filter.Position = 0;
            var reader = new StreamReader(filter, response.ContentEncoding);
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        finally
        {
            filter.Dispose();
            response.Filter = oldFilter;
        } 
    }
```

and use it like this during debug:

```
public PartialViewResult Reload()
{
    var result = RenderViewToString("Index",ViewData);
    return PartialView("Index");
}
```

**Extension method for Spark**:

```
    public static string RenderSparkToString(this Controller controller,
                                            string viewName, object viewData)
    {
        var view = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controller.ControllerContext, viewName).View;
        //Creating view context
        var viewContext = new ViewContext(controller.ControllerContext, view,
                                          controller.ViewData, controller.TempData);

        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        var writer = new StringWriter(sb);

        viewContext.View.Render(viewContext, writer);
        writer.Flush();
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I to pass the Model instance to the view in your example? Should I explicitly assign this.ViewData.Model before I invoke the helper?

Comment: Yes, you have to set Model in ViewData. Please copy my function again, because there was an error.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But for some reason it does not work with the Spark View Engine. A NullReferenceException is thrown when Spark tries to use the TextWriter. In your code, you pass null as the TextWriter argument (viewContext.View.Render(viewContext, null);).

Comment: I don't have experience with Spark view engine. You should look for different solution, because Spark has propably easier ways to render view to string. In Spark You should create Your own TextWriter, Render view to it, and then read from there. There is propably no need to filter HttpContext.Current.Response.

Comment: Thank. I'm accepting your answer as your solution works witht  he defaut MVC View Engine. I thought it would be the same thing with Spark. I'll research how to do the same with Spark. Thanks again.

Comment: As I said earlier, Spark makes it easier. I've added another extension method.

Comment: @LukLed: What you've done actually renders the view twice. Once with your method and second the default that gets actually sent to the client... And also... You're referring to Spark? None of your code relates to that custom view engine? Have you been talking about Razor all the time and mistakenly written Spark?

Comment: @RobertKoritnik: There should be `return Content(result);` instead of `return PartialView("Index");`. I was referring to Spark, not Razor. This answer is from 2009. Razor didn't exist at that time.

Comment: @LukLed: 2009... No Razor yes. I missed that detail. :) 3 long years ago. Actually in 2 days, exactly 3 years. :) Happy birthday answer!

Answer (score 2):

### Browser will show the result anyway

Why would you want to see it in debug mode, while you can see it in your browser anyway. That's where it goes afterwards anyway. If JSON is in question use Firefox + Firebug and you'll see all requests and responses with all related data and info.

If you tell us why exactly would you like to do this, we may suggest a better way of getting you there...

### A possible solution

The most likely solution to *jump in* while data is being rendered is to write your own view engine. And to make it easier on yourself, inherit from `RazorViewEngine`. This will likely spawn some more class inheriting (i.e. `RazorView`) but it would get you to a point where view actually get's generated and would do that in an efficient way: **view would get rendered only once**.

But on the other hand I'd question the rationale again. If you'd be looking at generated HTML right before it gets to the client, what point does that have? Because the next moment this same data gets sent to the client, where you can already observe it without any code manipulation and putting custom code in Asp.net MVC's extensibility points.

### Intermediate view manipulation in Asp.net MVC?

#### No such thing in Asp.net MVC...

You referred in a comment below to observing intermediate view changes during debug when doing things like `c.Controls.Add()`, but this just wouldn't work, because:

1. controller action doesn't manipulate views in any way shape or form; it merely prepares data for them and chooses which view will handle that data in however way they implement it; the *choosing* part can as well be abstracted away from controller actions in which case they'd only prepare data and handle it to some other view-choosing factory;
2. views are being generated in whole by view engines using ASPX/ASCX/CSHTML files merely as templates:

   - Web forms view engine does parse those templates into object hierarchy, but if most of your view's code is static HTML (which it should be), majority of those controls will just be literals;
   - Razor view engine doesn't use any control hierarchy object model as Web forms engine does; Razor views are just strings, that engine parses character-by-character, line-by-line looking for special directives where it needs to insert view data in; no controls whatsoever...

All in all: **no intermediate view manipulation**. You can however debug your view while it's being parsed by the view engine though. Just put breakpoints inside a directive within the view.

Comment: Because when you're debugging and your code does stuff like `c.Controls.Add()`, you want to see what's already in there. It would be nice to see the HTML to be rendered at a certain point in the code.

Comment: @styfle: that's true, but when you're doing `c.Controls.Add()` you're manipulating hierarchy objects that will be **later** translated to HTML. You can of course view object tree that's being built of course... `Page.Controls` is your starting point...

Comment: @styfle: ...makes me think... What in the world does `c.Controls.Add()` have to do with Asp.net MVC? And also: accepted answer doesn't give you any intermediate results. It just returns resulting view as HTML string. No mid-manipulation as you implied in your comment here... Which of course wouldn't be possible to do in MVC. For something like that, you'd have to debug view code and not controller action. But even then... You wouldn't be seeing resulting HTML but merely view model items as you're rendering them in a *string*. View's HTML is nothing else but a string to a Razor engine.

Comment: @styfle: I edited my answer adding additional info that may be of some help. If nothing else at least from an explanation point of Asp.net MVC inner working.

Answer (score 1):

What prevents you from just hitting the Route that renders the partial view and view source?